# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to select some files for a package but I have an error!

SingleproductController:

```
 public  function syncFiles(Request $request , $id){
      $files = product_file::all();
      $product_item = Singleproduct::find($id);
      $product_files = $product_item->file()->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        return view('admin.SingleProduct.productSync'  , compact('files' , 'product_files'));
   }
```

```
public  function updatesyncFiles(Request $request , $id){
       $product_item = Singleproduct::find($id);
       $files = $request->input('files');
         if ($product_item && is_array($files)){
           $product_item->file()->sync($files);
         }
}
```

blade:

```
  @if( $files && count($files) > 0)
        <form action="{{ route('product.updatesync_files')}}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field()  }}
            <h3 style="color: black; ">فایل مربوطه:</h3>
            <section class="panel">
                <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
            <ul>
                @foreach($files as $file)
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="{{ $file->file_id  }}" {{ isset($id) && in_array($file->id,$id) ? 'checked':''  }}>
                        {{ $file->file_name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit_product_files" value="ذخیره اطلاعات">
            </div>
                </table>
            </section>
        </form>
    @endif
```

route:

```
Route::get('/product/sync_files/{id}', 'SingleproductController@syncFiles')->name('product.sync_files');
Route::post('/product/updatesync_files/{id}', 'SingleproductController@updateSyncFiles')->name('product.updatesync_files');
```

the error is: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: You have no action for your form?

Comment: Currently there is not action in you form. Also which blade file is this? @if( $files && count($files) > 0)
        <form action="" method="post">

Comment: I edited it and now I have new error : " Missing required parameters for [Route: product.updatesync_files] [URI: " And I really don't know which parameter should pass!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not specified action on your form (or specified action is empty) ot redirects on same url where form is, 
In this case solution will be to specify correct action to your form.

As I can see you have following route with name `product.updatesync_files`:

```
Route::post('/product/updatesync_files/{id}', 'SingleproductController@updateSyncFiles')->name('product.updatesync_files');
```

You can add this route to your form:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.updatesync_files') }}" method="post">
```

But you have required parameter in route `{id}`. I can't figure out what this id actually is. 
If you know it you can add this to your form

```
<form action="{{ route('product.updatesync_files', ['id' => $id]) }}" method="post">
```

Comment: I did it and now I have new error:" Undefined variable: id "

Comment: You really don't have variable id, you have to know what parameter is it and place that variable there

Comment: as it shows: Route::post('/product/updatesync_files/{id}', 'SingleproductController@updateSyncFiles')->name('product.updatesync_files'); It is id!

Comment: I don't undrestand what should I use instead of id

Comment: You have this in your 'updatesyncFiles` method. `$product_item = Singleproduct::find($id);` , so that is `Singleproduct` Id

Comment: when I use $product_item I receive Undefined variable: product_item  error

Comment: Of course you will get undefined variable because you don't have it in view. Also It requires only id not whole product or another object. Please look at laravel and php documentations and learn  basics, after that learn how to pass variable from controller to view and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

if you are uploading files in your form you are missing enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute this is important uploading files.

Here is your form will be

```
<form action="{{ route('product.updatesync_files')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

for more information read this.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp